# Can not load mcrypt with php-buildpack

Tags: php, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I can not load mcrypt.so. It is supposed to be activated by default with the newest php-buildback. So I do not specify it in the additional config file or options.json.

But I get an error:

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/vcap/app/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mcrypt.so' - libmcrypt.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

This is on my local machine (Pivotal Cloud Foundry Dev) and staging (Swisscom Application Cloud).

I noted that my additional ini folder is different from the one specified in the documentation (.bp-config/php/php.ini.d/):

`Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /home/vcap/app/.bp-config/php/php.d`

So I moved my additional ini file in the "php.d" folder.

Thanks for any hint

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> It is supposed to be activated by default with the newest php-buildback.

It's been activated by default for a long time.  Check `.bp-config/options.json` and see if you have `PHP_EXTENSIONS` set there.  This would override the default.

> But I get an error:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/vcap/app/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mcrypt.so' - libmcrypt.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm not able to reproduce this with the latest build pack (as of writing 4.3.35).  The error is saying that it cannot find the library `libmcrypt.so.4`, which is used by the `mcrypt` extension.  This should exist in `/home/vcap/app/php/lib`, as it's installed there by the build pack.

I would suggest running `cf ssh` to check and see if this file exists for your app.  Also check that you are not overriding the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which is how the libraries in `/home/vcap/app/php/lib` are located.  And, of course, try using the latest PHP build pack.

> I noted that my additional ini folder is different from the one specified in the documentation (.bp-config/php/php.ini.d/):

That's normal.  Use the path set in the documentation, `.bp-config/php/php.ini.d/*.ini`.

Hope that helps!